# What does the following mean?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

can someone explain what does the below statement does ?

```
def commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Invokes the 'shell' to execute `git rev-parse` on HEAD this gets the SHA1 of the revision.
So the `commit` variable is the SHA1 of the commit on HEAD.

Comment: @iBug The language is Groovy

Answer (score 1):

First thing need to understand is

1. what is `sh` function?
2. You need to understand what is `returnStdout`?
3. You need to know what is `git rev-parse HEAD`?

for `git rev-parse` you need to read this [git-rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)

If you want to get the stdout just use `returnStdout` as true

> Actually it try to extract commit information